# Can command blocks teleport the a person closest to a set of coords instead of the command block itself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a teleport system in Minecraft, but the command blocks that have the teleport command (`/tp @p x y z`) are far away from the pressure plate I use to activate it. I use this world with other people, so I'm worried that other people might be closer to the command blocks than I am, and they will accidentally get teleported.

Is there any way to make it so the command blocks teleport the closest person to a certain set of coordinates instead of the command block itself?

Comment: why not put the block next to the pressure plate?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I can only speculate, maybe he wants a switch where you can deactivate the teleporter.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. It's pretty simple, use the following code:

```
/tp @p[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=0] *tp coordinates*
```

Where the values x, y, z define the center of the search (the player nearest to these coordinates would get teleported) and r defines the radius of the search. If you don't want to limit the radius omit r.

Do not use decimal values for the search center, this will not work.

See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_block#Arguments) for more info.

Comment: You may want to mention the wiki page which contains those arguments, plus more: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_block#Arguments

Comment: Also, you can use the `r` argument to set the radius, and only pick the nearest player if he also is within a certain radius of that center (in case there is more than just a pressure plate that you want to trigger the redstone).

Comment: ***This answer is outdated, [updated answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378874/258509).***

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely make it much easier if the command blocks were directly adjacent or one redstone-conducting block away. I don't know if this would be inconvenient for you, because I can't see how your command blocks are set up in your world.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

The command would be:

```
/tp @p[x=0,y=0,z=0] 5 10 5
```

to teleport a player to 5, 10, 5. To specify a radius:

```
/tp @p[x=0,y=0,z=0,distance=..1] 5 10 5
```

That command tests for a distance of 1 or smaller.

Comment: The change seems to have taken place in 1.13, but I can't confirm. If someone could confirm that would be great.