# Set facing direction using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to set the direction you face when you set a new spawn or teleport to a new location?

For example, if I create a notice board in the spawn location facing north, and every one keeps spawning facing east, there's a possibility they may not see the board.

Or if I teleport to a new location, I might always end up facing a wall(east), when I want to spawn in the new location facing down a corridor(north).

So can I set the direction a player faces when they spawn or teleport?

Comment: Make another place to spawn and teleport them to fake spawn with a 20hz clock. Following is the syntax for `/tp` command: `/tp [target entity] <x> <y> <z> [<rx> <ry>]`; `<rx>` is vertical rotation and `<ry>` is horizontal rotation. See http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#tp

Comment: @FinnRayment to be honest my knowledge of this isn't really good enough to define it as "the right" answer, and I have not yet had a chance to test it myself. The only other reason I haven't marked it as the accepted answer yet is because I like to allow a "grace" period (if you will) to allow other people to answer as well. If your answer is correct (which it is very likely to be) I will accept it, as well as up voting, which I have already done.

Comment: @Ben Sure thing. I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based off of *QbsidianH20's* comment, to do it with **commands only**, follow the below guide which extra information can be found [**here**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp).

To start off, the command you are looking for is shown below:

`/tp [target player] <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]`

Syntax for the above command:

- `[target player]` is the player that will be teleported.
- `<x>` is the X coordinate the targeted player will be teleported to.
- `<y>` is the Y coordinate the targeted player will be teleported to.
- `<z>` is the Z coordinate the targeted player will be teleported to.
- `[<y-rot> <x-rot>]` is the rotation on the Y and X axis that the player will be rotated accordingly on.

Guide for usage:

1. Firstly, find your position on the map. Press **F3** and jot down your X, Y & Z coordinates located on the left.
2. Then type into the chat bar `/tp [target player] <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]` replacing `<x>`, `<y>` and `<z>` with your coordinates you wrote down.
3. Then, change `<y-rot>` and `<x-rot>` with the angles you want.

**Angles/Rotation Description from [Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp) page**

> **y-rot (optional)**
>
> Specifies the horizontal rotation (-180.0 for due north, -90.0 for due east, 0.0 for due south, 90.0 for due west, to 179.9 for just west of north, before wrapping back around to -180.0). Tilde notation can be used to specify a rotation relative to the target's previous rotation.
>
> ---
>
> **x-rot (optional)**
>
> Specifies the vertical rotation (-90.0 for straight up to 90.0 for straight down). Tilde notation can be used to specify a rotation relative to the target's previous rotation.

---

As for when the player spawns, if you are using Bukkit for the **setspawn** command, using plugins like [**this**](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/setspawn/) automatically make the facing direction wherever you were looking when you executed the **setspawn** command.

If not, put a pressure plate down on the spawn block, a command block under that and teleport the nearest player wherever you want (a good suggestion *again* from *QbsidianH20* would be a fake spawn), by inputting the below command into the command block:

> `/tp @p [x=0,y=0,z=0,r=0] tp coordinates`
>
> Where the values x, y, z define the center of the search (the player nearest to these coordinates would get teleported) and r defines the radius of the search. If you don't want to limit the radius omit r.
>
> Do not use decimal values for the search center, this will not work.

- Excerpt from [**this**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147641/can-command-blocks-teleport-the-a-person-closest-to-a-set-of-coords-instead-of-t) Arqade question.

---

Good luck!

Comment: It might be important to note that the rotation functionality of the `tp` command is available with Minecraft 1.8 and newer; sadly, there doesn't seem to be a solution for Minecraft 1.7

Answer (score 3):

Use `/execute in <dimension> run tp <selector> <x> <y> <z> <rx> <ry>`. PS: <rx> is your vertical rotation, <ry> is your horizontal rotation. Also, if you want to do this faster, doing F3+C will copy your exact location into a command that will teleport to where you did F3+C.

Answer (score 1):

The information provided above is correct, but an example helps me:

```
/tp [Player] [x] [y] [z] [x-rot] [y-rot]
/tp @s -5066 142 -11026 200 -8
/tp @s -4225 101 -15795 90 0
```

Comment: Which answer do you mean by "above"? Answer sorting/position can be changed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `/tp [Player] [x] [y] [z]`

Lets talk about a circle...

A circle has 360 degrees.

```
/tp [Player] [x] [y] [z] [x-rot] [y-rot]
```

x is vertical, y is horizontal.

Hope I helped!

Comment: so, you can enter in the amount of degrees you want them turned? if so you should make that more clear

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what you want, but I think this is the answer.

After pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>, look at "facing" and at the end of this line, there should be a few numbers, like 89.0 -5.6 or 7.9 40.1, look at the direction you want the player to look at, and copy those numbers, and put them at the end of your tp command.

Example: `/tp @p ~ ~ ~ 6.7 7.9`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make a block face another direction(ex; button, log, sign) you can use the /setblock command. Here's an example `/setblock minecraft:button[facing=north]` you can replace north with any answer you want. If you want it to face up or down you can use `/setblock minecraft:button[face=ceiling]` or `/setblock minecraft:button[face=floor]` prospectively.

Answer (score -1):

[This mod](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/spawncommands-spawn-commands-teleport) may be the answer for 1.7. It says in the description that you can place a spawn, then when you spawn back to it, it will face you in the same direction you were facing when you made the spawn.

Answer (score -4):

After not getting to understand this here or on Youtube, I did some research and came with a video of mine:

It explains how to use the `y-rot` and `x-rot` parameters in the `/tp` command: `Y-rot` is the horizontal rotation (-180.0 is north, -90.0 is east, 0.0 is south, 90.0 is west) and `x-rot` is the vertical rotation (90 is down, 0 forward, -90 up).

Comment: Can you write what the video is talking about to your answer? This is considered a link-only answer.

Answer (score -4):

If you're on a server and there's Essentials installed, use /minecraft:tp. Otherwise, it won't work!

Comment: That is just not true, as you can see in the other answers.