# How to make the player face a certain direction with /setworldspawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've created an SMP, and I would like players to spawn facing West. Unfortunately, the world spawn causes new players to first spawn facing South.

Can this be changed with the `/setworldspawn` command?

Comment: [related, possible dupe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199784/set-facing-direction-using-commands)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact, the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setworldspawn) says that `/setworldspawn` has an option for facing direction as a yaw angle parameter.

It also states which numbers correspond to which directions: −180 for north, −90 for east, 0 for south, and 90 for west.

So to change the world spawn facing angle to west, just specify 90 in the `/setworldspawn` command.

Comment: Alright, thank you for answering ym question! :D